# Does Sharepoint automatically synchronise to source data location?

Tags: sharepoint, synchronization

Does a dragged and dropped folder to Sharepoint stand-alone, or is it automatically synchronised with  the original folder?

i.e. I created a site in Sharepoint in Microsoft 365, dragged and dropped a load of folders to take advantage of the document library. Can I delete the original folders, or will it "synchronise" and delete them from Sharepoint too?

I ask because...I'm staring at some empty Sharepoint folders!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could synchronised these original folders to Onedrive.
[image]

Then, select the empty folders what you want to delete,
[image]

Click Sync button in SharePoint Online library.
[image]

It will sync your folders in real time.

Comment: Is there any update on this thread? Comment here if you still need any help.